# how to open xampp in browser (localhost)? I used to open xampp when i installed it but not able to do so now

Tags: xampp, localhost

[not able to view xampp anymore in my localhost sever. It worked when I installed it, but now after making some changes I am not able to view the index page of xampp. I actually need to change some features in my phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krRkB.jpg)

Comment: what changes did you make?
Please mention complete information.

Comment: I actually deleted everything from htdocs tomake new html files

Comment: htdocs had the content for the Xampp homepage too. You have deleted it. Please reinstall Xampp. In fact, it actually contained all the functions and stuff for Xampp dashboard too.

Comment: htdocs had everything related to Xampp Dashboard.

Comment: I don't understand-How did you delete the entire htdocs? Have you checked if it's still present in your recycle bin?

Comment: Yes I did delete everything, but as per your suggestion I reinstalled it and it worked. Thanks a lot Mathews!!!

Comment: My Pleasure. I am glad that it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

htdocs had the content for the Xampp homepage too. You have deleted it. Please reinstall Xampp. In fact, it actually contained all the functions and stuff for Xampp dashboard too.